# Hazelcast cache not getting empty to store updated records

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to make my hazelcast map empty after 5 minutes so that i can put updated Db records in it. But its not getting null and still contains old records.Below is my hazlecast.xml file in hazelcast cache server.

```
<map name="CdnConfig">
  <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
  <backup-count>0</backup-count>
  <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
  <time-to-live-seconds>300</time-to-live-seconds>
  <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
  <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
  <max-size policy="PER_NODE">1000</max-size>
  <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
  <min-eviction-check-millis>5000</min-eviction-check-millis>
</map>
```

My Java code is like:

```
List<CdnConfigDto> dataList=(List<CdnConfigDto>)hazelCastCache.getDataFromCache("CdnConfig", key);
   if (dataList != null) {
        LOGGER.info("HazelcastCache conatains records ");
 } else {
       LOGGER.info("HazelcastCache does not contains records ");
       dataList = configurationService.getDataFromDB();
       hazelCastCache.addDataToCache("CdnConfig", key, dataList);
        }
```

Declaration of hazelcast:

```
   private static HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;
   private static HazelCastCache instance = null;
   public static HazelCastCache getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

 public static void initCache() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (HazelCastCache.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new HazelCastCache();
            }
        }
    }
}

private HazelCastCache() {
    hazelcastInstance = HazelcastCacheInstance.getHazelcastInstance();
}
```

Method implementation of getDataFromCache():--

```
 public Object getDataFromCache(String mapName, Object key) {
    Object data = null;
    IMap<Object, Object> hazelMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap(mapName);
    if (null != hazelMap) {
        data = hazelMap.get(key);
    }

    return data;

}
```

Comment: `hazelcast.xml` or `hazlecast.xml`?

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `hazelCastCache` and method implementation of `getDataFromCache` & `addDataToCache` ?

Comment: Hi! Happy New Yr..Actually I took another route,instead of depending on eviction policy,I am doing cache reset whenever there is any CRUD operation. But still would like to know why above approach is not working. @Desai: I have posted code above..@noctarius: Its hazelcast.xml

Answer (score 0):

Did you try hazelMap.get(key); after 5 minutes?